# Suggestions on tile edging

Tags: bathroom, tile

We recently tiled out bathroom and when installing a bath tube ledge the trim we installed wasn’t cut at a 45 angle. A little unsure as to how best to finish this end piece of tile

First image is current situation

Second image is if I add trim leaving a small gap at the end. Thought about filling it, sanding and painting this gap

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if the place you bought the trim from has end caps which are common also

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have (or can get) additional trim molding, you could cut a piece long and miter an "end return" that will cover the square-cut end of the original piece. You do it by mitering a "plug" and glueing it in place; something like this:

[image]